# Lebesgue measure (transformation)

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am working on the following task:

Calculate $\lambda(A), A=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2\leq z \leq \sqrt{3-2(x^2+y^2)}$.

We have recently shown: $\lambda(\phi(M))=\int_M|detD_{\phi}|d\lambda$.
So my idea is to find a diffeomorphism $\phi:M\to A$ so that $\phi(M)=A$. However, I don´t know what $M$ is supposed to be.
Or do you know an easier way to calculate it?

Any help or hints is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When a region has Jordan content, it has Lebesgue measure and the two coincide! Just use iterated integrals as you would do in a calculus IV course.

Comment: (In other words, simply calculate $\int\limits_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int\limits_0^1 dr \int\limits_{r^2}^{\sqrt{3-2r^2}} dz\ r.$)

Comment: So by your notation, $M$ is
$$M=\left\{(r,\theta,z):0< r\leq 1, 0< \theta\leq 2\pi, r^2\leq z\leq \sqrt{3-2r^2}\right\}$$
and $\phi$ is the diffeomorphism corresponding to the conversion from cylindrical to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answers! But can you explain to me how one can get the cylindric coordinates? I have already read some online articles but don´t know how to transfer this to sets. Thank you!